# Larvel Update and Destroy route not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-artisan

[image]

The accept button has the route `route('members.update', $member->id)`

The deny button has the route `route('members.destroy',   $member->id)`

These are the cards:

```
@foreach ($members as $member)
                <div class="my-1 px-1 w-full md:w-1/2 lg:my-4 lg:px-4 lg:w-1/3">
                    <article class="bg-white overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg">

                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between leading-tight p-2 md:p-4 w-max">
                            <div class="w-1/2">
                                <small class="text-gray-600">Full name:</small>
                                <h1 class="text-lg pr-2"> {{ $member->firstname }} {{ $member->lastname }} </h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="w-1/2">
                                <small class="text-gray-600">Birthdate:</small>
                                <h1 class="text-lg">{{ date('d-m-Y', strtotime($member->birthdate)) }}</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between leading-tight p-2 md:p-4">
                            <div class="w-1/2">
                                <small class="text-gray-600">Student id:</small>
                                <h1 class="text-lg pr-2">{{ $member->studentid }}</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="w-1/2">
                                <small class="text-gray-600">Discord:</small>
                                <h1 class="text-lg">{{ $member->discordname }}{{ $member->discordtag }}</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <footer class="flex items-center  leading-tight p-2 md:p-4 justify-start">
                            <form method="PATCH" action="{{ route('members.update', $member->id) }}">
                                @method('PATCH')
                                <button class="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded mr-2">Accept</button>
                                @csrf
                            </form>
                            <form method="DELETE" action="{{ route('members.destroy',   $member->id) }}">
                                @method('DELETE')
                                <button class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Deny</button>
                                @csrf
                            </form>
                        </footer>
                    </article>
                </div>
            @endforeach
```

And this is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Member;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MemberController extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        $members = Member::where(['status' => false])->get();
        return view('dashboard')->with(['members' => $members]);
    }

    public function show($id) {
        $members = Member::where(['id' => $id])->get();
        return view('dashboard')->with(['members' => $members]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'firstname' => 'required|max:255|alpha|min:2',
            'lastname' => 'required|max:255|alpha|min:2',
            'studentid' => 'required|integer|alpha_num',
            'birthdate' => 'required|date',
            'discordname' => 'required|max:255',
            'discordtag' => 'required|max:255|size:5'
        ]);

        $member = new Member;

        $member->firstname = $request->firstname;
        $member->lastname = $request->lastname;
        $member->studentid = $request->studentid;
        $member->birthdate = $request->birthdate;
        $member->discordname = $request->discordname;
        $member->discordtag = $request->discordtag;
        $member->status = false;

        $member->save();

        return \redirect()->route('index');
    }

    public function update($id) {
        die;
        $member = Member::find($id);
        $member->status = 1;
        $member->save();
        return \redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }

    /**
     * TODO - SEND EMAIL ON DELETE
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function destroy($id) {
        DB::delete('delete members where id = ?', [$id]);
    }

    public function accepted($id) {
        update($id);
    }
}
```

My routes:
[image]

When i click the accept or deny button it sends me to this link: http://hit.localhost.nl/members/3?_method=PATCH&_token=0g5odDLEKCicceDOf4EuPMGIB1X95cwWHGMxMqcR

And runs the show() function instead of the update or destroy functions. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`method="PATCH"` and `method="DELETE"` don't exist, just `get`, `post` and `dialog`. Change both of those to `method="post"`.

Comment: Oh snap this was it! Thank you for the help!